# Difference in referencing an object using object.key = value and object['key'] = value

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between referencing an object with `object.key = value` and `object['key'] = value` For example if I had an object call `var myObj = {};`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quote notation allows for arbitrary keys, (like `console.log({' 1a':3}[' 1a'])`, whereas the dot syntax can only be used with keys that begin with a letter.

Comment: How were you able to answer this *correctly* closed question, moreover with something that just looks like a comment ? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40955994/timeline

Comment: @Kaiido I have no idea :)